# A function that returns a pointer to an one dimensional array is valid C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

To return a two dimensional array with variable dimension lengths allocated dynamically inside a function I've been returning a pointer to an one dimensional array like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int (*create_2D_matrix(size_t lin, size_t col))[];

int main() {
    size_t lin = 4, col = 5;

    int (*m)[col] = create_2D_matrix(lin, col);

    for (size_t i=0; i<lin*col; i++){
        m[i/col][i%col] = (int) i+1;
    }

    for (size_t i=0; i<lin; i++){
        for (size_t j=0; j<col; j++){
            printf("%2d ", m[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(m);

    return 0;
}

int (*create_2D_matrix(size_t lin, size_t col))[] {
    int (*matrix)[col] = malloc(lin * sizeof *matrix);
    if (matrix == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation of 2D matrix has failed.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

GCC compiles this with no warnings (I've tried to activate several warning options that might be related, but nothing I tried complained about it), online Clang also doesn't seem to have a problem with it, and it works as intended.

But when looking what are the recommended ways to return multi dimensional arrays the answers I've found recommend something like passing it as a pointer to a parameter of the function, so that the address to the allocated memory can be set to the pointer inside the function and returned through that, or even to use a normal one dimensional array and do some index math to simulate a multi dimensional array.

I haven't found anything suggesting returning a pointer to a one dimensional array like the code above being mentioned as an alternative method for two dimensional arrays.

So my question is: Is what I've been doing valid C code? Can I return a pointer to an array of variable length like this?

Comment: Also note you are declaring a *pointer-to-a-Variable-Length-Array* of `int` (`col` of them). While the VLA was introduced in C99 -- it was made optional for compilers to support as of C11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this code is correct. Personally I would use a typedef as I find the syntax for returning pointer-to-array a bit ugly, e.g.:

```
typedef int intarray[];

intarray *create_2D_matrix(size_t lin, size_t col);
```

You may find this technique is not mentioned a lot because many C programmers seem to be stuck in the 1980s .

It would also be possible to return `void *`,  which allows your same allocation function to allocate space for an array of any number of dimensions,  whether this is a benefit or a drawback is up to you I guess :)

And in both cases the malloc line could also be written as `void *matrix = malloc(sizeof(int[lin][col]));`